# Use schema to convert ConsumerRecord value to Dataframe in spark-kafka

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I am using Spark 2.0.2, with Kafka 0.11.0, and 
I am trying to consume message from kafka in spark streaming. Following is the code:

```
val topics = "notes"
val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
  "bootstrap.servers" -> "localhost:7092",
  "schema.registry.url" -> "http://localhost:7070",
  "group.id" -> "connect-cluster1",
  "value.deserializer" -> "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer",
  "key.deserializer" -> "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer"
)
val topicSet: Set[String] = Set(topics)
val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
  SparkStream.ssc,
  PreferConsistent,
  Subscribe[String, String](topicSet, kafkaParams)
)
stream.foreachRDD ( rdd => {
  rdd.foreachPartition(iterator => {
    while (iterator.hasNext) {
      val next = iterator.next()
      println(next.value())
    }
  })
})
```

If Kafka message contain records, the output would be:

```
{"id": "4164a489-a0bb-4ea1-a259-b4e2a4519eee", "createdat": 1505312886984, "createdby": "karthik", "notes": "testing20"}
{"id": "4164a489-a0bb-4ea1-a259-b4e2a4519eee", "createdat": 1505312890472, "createdby": "karthik", "notes": "testing21"}
```

Thus, received message is Avro decoded as seen from the consumerRecord's value.
Now I need those records in a dataframe format, but I do not know how to proceed from here, even with the schema at hand as follows:

```
val sr : CachedSchemaRegistryClient = new CachedSchemaRegistryClient("http://localhost:7070", 1000)
val m = sr.getLatestSchemaMetadata(topics + "-value")
val schemaId = m.getId
val schemaString = m.getSchema

val schemaRegistry : CachedSchemaRegistryClient = new CachedSchemaRegistryClient("http://localhost:7070", 1000)
val decoder: KafkaAvroDecoder = new KafkaAvroDecoder(schemaRegistry)
val parser = new Schema.Parser()
val avroSchema = parser.parse(schemaString)
println(avroSchema)
```

with the schema printed as follows:

`{"type":"record","name":"notes","namespace":"db","fields":[{"name":"id","type":["null","string"],"default":null},{"name":"createdat","type":["null",{"type":"long","connect.version":1,"connect.name":"org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Timestamp","logicalType":"timestamp-millis"}],"default":null},{"name":"createdby","type":["null","string"],"default":null},{"name":"notes","type":["null","string"],"default":null}],"connect.name":"db.notes"}`

Can anyone help me understand how to get the dataframe from the consumer record's value? I have looked at other questions such as [Use schema to convert AVRO messages with Spark to DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39049648/use-schema-to-convert-avro-messages-with-spark-to-dataframe/39072520), [Handling schema changes in running Spark Streaming application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41193764/handling-schema-changes-in-running-spark-streaming-application?noredirect=1&lq=1), but they are not dealing with the consumerRecord in the firstplace.

Comment: I'm running into a similar situation. Were you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 4):

You can use below snippet :
stream is the DStream of consumer record returned from kafkaUtils api of kafka010 :

```
stream.foreachRDD(rdd =>
    if (!rdd.isEmpty()) {
        val sqlContext = SQLContext.getOrCreate(rdd.sparkContext)
        import sqlContext.implicits._
        val topicValueStrings = rdd.map(record => (record.value()).toString)
        val df = sqlContext.read.json(topicValueStrings)
        df.show()
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to scala\kafka\spark myself, so I'm not sure if this exactly answers the question, but it would have helped me out.  I'm sure there is a better way than this, so hopefully someone with more experience can come along and provide a better answer.

```
// KafkaRDD
stream.foreachRDD { rdd => {

  // pull the values I'm looking for into a string array
  var x = rdd.map(row => row.value()).collect()

  // convert to dataframe
  val df = spark.createDataFrame(x).toDF("record")

  // write data frame to datastore (MySQL in my case)
  df.write
    .mode(SaveMode.Append)
    .jdbc(url, table, props)

  }
}
```