# Avro format deserialization in Spark structured stream

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, avro, spark-structured-streaming

I'm using Spark Structured Streaming as described on
[this page](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html).

I get correct message from Kafka topic but value is in Avro format. Is there some way to deserialize Avro records (something like `KafkaAvroDeserializer` approach)?

Comment: Is the schema in the message? Or is it generated by Confluent serializers with only a schema ID?

Comment: I'm using schema registry.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're not using Kafka Streams instead? Also, as the Spark documentation says, you need to deserialize values from Dataframe operations as the ByteDeserializer is always used https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#kafka-specific-configurations

Comment: Several posts I've found just use normal Spark Streaming. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41193764/handling-schema-changes-in-running-spark-streaming-application

Comment: Check out this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48882723/integrating-spark-structured-streaming-with-the-kafka-schema-registry/49182004#49182004 Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

**Spark >= 2.4**

You can use [`from_avro`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-avro.html#to_avro-and-from_avro) function from [`spark-avro`](https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro) library.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.avro._

val schema: String = ???
df.withColumn("value", from_avro($"value", schema))
```

**Spark < 2.4**

- Define a function which takes `Array[Byte]` (serialized object):

  ```scala
  import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag

  def decode[T : TypeTag](bytes: Array[Byte]): T = ???
  ```

  which will deserialize Avro data and create object, that can be stored in a `Dataset`.
- Create `udf` based on the function.

  ```scala
  val decodeUdf  = udf(decode _)
  ```
- Call `udf` on `value`

  ```scala
  val df = spark
    .readStream
    .format("kafka")
    ...
    .load()

  df.withColumn("value", decodeUdf($"value"))
  ```

Comment: Do you know recommend me some deserializer, witch is good for this problem ?

Comment: These solutions don't work when using Confluent Schema Registry

Comment: from_avro required the schema to always match with the actual record schema and can't take an evolved schema. So, this solution might be applicable only when using schema registry.

Comment: from_avro is giving the data in \u00001 format. Its not deserializing them