# How to use Confluent Schema Registry with from_avro standard function?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, avro, spark-structured-streaming, confluent-schema-registry

My Kafka and Schema Registry are based on Confluent Community Platform 5.2.2, and My Spark has version 2.4.4. I started Spark REPL env with:

```sh
./bin/spark-shell --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.4,org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.11:2.4.4
```

And setup Kafka source for spark session:

```scala
val brokerServers = "my_confluent_server:9092"
val topicName = "my_kafka_topic_name" 
val df = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", brokerServers)
  .option("subscribe", topicName)
  .load()
```

And I got schema information about key and value with:

```scala
import io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService
val schemaRegistryURL = "http://my_confluent_server:8081"
val restService = new RestService(schemaRegistryURL)
val keyRestResponseSchemaStr: String = restService.getLatestVersionSchemaOnly(topicName + "-key")
val valueRestResponseSchemaStr: String = restService.getLatestVersionSchemaOnly(topicName + "-value")
```

Firstly, if I queried it with writeStream for "**key**", i.e.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.avro._
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.Trigger
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import java.time.LocalDateTime
val query = df.writeStream
  .outputMode("append")
  .foreachBatch((batchDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) => {
    val rstDF = batchDF
      .select(
        from_avro($"key", keyRestResponseSchemaStr).as("key"),
        from_avro($"value", valueRestResponseSchemaStr).as("value"))

    println(s"${LocalDateTime.now} --- Batch ${batchId}, ${batchDF.count} rows")
    //rstDF.select("value").show
    rstDF.select("key").show
  })
  .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("120 seconds"))
  .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

There is no errors, even count of rows are shown, but I could not got any data.

```
2019-09-16T10:30:16.984 --- Batch 0, 0 rows
+---+
|key|
+---+
+---+

2019-09-16T10:32:00.401 --- Batch 1, 27 rows
+---+
|key|
+---+
| []|
| []|
| []|
| []|
| []|
| []|
| []|
| []|
| []|
| []|
| []|
| []|
| []|
| []|
| []|
| []|
| []|
| []|
| []|
| []|
+---+
only showing top 20 rows
```

But if I select "**value**":

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.avro._
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.Trigger
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import java.time.LocalDateTime
val query = df.writeStream
  .outputMode("append")
  .foreachBatch((batchDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) => {
    val rstDF = batchDF
      .select(
        from_avro($"key", keyRestResponseSchemaStr).as("key"),
        from_avro($"value", valueRestResponseSchemaStr).as("value"))

    println(s"${LocalDateTime.now} --- Batch ${batchId}, ${batchDF.count} rows")
    rstDF.select("value").show
    //rstDF.select("key").show
  })
  .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("120 seconds"))
  .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

I got message:

```
2019-09-16T10:34:54.287 --- Batch 0, 0 rows
+-----+
|value|
+-----+
+-----+

2019-09-16T10:36:00.416 --- Batch 1, 19 rows
19/09/16 10:36:03 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 3)
org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Malformed data. Length is negative: -1
    at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.doReadBytes(BinaryDecoder.java:336)
    at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.readString(BinaryDecoder.java:263)
    at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.readString(ResolvingDecoder.java:201)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readString(GenericDatumReader.java:422)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readString(GenericDatumReader.java:414)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:181)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:153)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readField(GenericDatumReader.java:232)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:222)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:175)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:153)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:145)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.avro.AvroDataToCatalyst.nullSafeEval(AvroDataToCatalyst.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.serializefromobject_doConsume_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:255)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

So I think there are two levels fo problems:

1. Firstly, there are different avro deserialization logic for **key** and **value**, and current "from_avro" only support **key**, rather than **value**
2. Even for key, there is no error, but deserializer of "from_avro" could not get real data.

Do you think I have any wrong steps? Or, should from_avro and to_avro need be enhanced?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Your key and value are entirely byte arrays, and are prefixed with integer values for their IDs. Spark-Avro does not support that format, only "Avro container object" formats that contain the schema as part of the record.

In other words, you need to [invoke the functions from Confluent deserializers](https://github.com/xebia-france/spark-structured-streaming-blog/blob/master/src/main/scala/AvroConsumer.scala#L28-L39) , not the "plain Avro" deserializers, in order to first get Avro objects, then you can put schemas on those

> Spark should enhance from_avro and to_avro?

They should, but they won't. Ref [SPARK-26314](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-26314). Sidenote that Databricks **does** offer Schema Registry integration with functions of the same name, only to add to the confusion

The workaround would be to use this library - https://github.com/AbsaOSS/ABRiS

Or see other solutions at [Integrating Spark Structured Streaming with the Confluent Schema Registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48882723/integrating-spark-structured-streaming-with-the-confluent-schema-registry)

Comment: Thanks a lot, cricket_007. Actually I referred to your solution in the last link. My current workaround is using KafkaAvroDeserializer.

Comment: And then transform values to DataFrame using spark.read.json