# Kafka with Spark 3.0.1 Structured Streaming : ClassException: org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition; class invalid for deserialization

Tags: java, pyspark, apache-kafka, avro, spark-structured-streaming

> I am trying to read the kafka messages in google dataproc using
> pyspark - structured streaming.
>
> Version details are :
>
> 1. dataproc image verison is 2.0.0-RC22-debian10 (to get pyspark 3.0.1 verison with delta lake 0.7.0 as I have to finally write this data to
>    delta hosted on google storage)
> 2. pyspark version 3.0.1 and python version used by pyspark is 3.7.3
> 3. The packages I am using is    org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.0.1
>    io.delta:delta-core_2.12:0.7.0
>    org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:3.0.1
>
> Snippet of the code is :

```
__my_dir = os.path.dirname("<directory_path>") 
jsonFormatSchema = open(os.path.join(__my_dir, 'avro_schema_file.avsc'), "r").read() 

df = spark \    
    .readStream \    
    .format("kafka") \   
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "<kafka_broker>") \   
    .option("subscribe", "<kafka_topic>") \    
    .option("startingOffsets", "latest") \    
    .load()\    
    .select(from_avro("value", jsonFormatSchema)
    .alias("element"))

df.printSchema()
 
df_output =     df.select("element.after.id","element.after.name","element.after.attribute","element.after.quantity")

StreamQuery = ( df_output.writeStream \ 
               .format("delta") \   
               .outputMode("append") \   
               .option("checkpointLocation","<check_point_location>") \   
               .trigger(once=True) \    
               .start("<target_delta_table>") \    )
```

> Error I am getting is :

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition;
class invalid for deserialization
```

> Why spark fails to deserialize TopicPartition and how can I solve it?

Comment: Same configuration as your but with delta 0.8.0 and without spark-avro. I get the error when the master is "yarn". This disappear if the master is set to local. However, I am not able to find a solution

Comment: Your question helped me fix version dependency.

Answer (score 0):

The following post helped to resolve this issue :
[How to use Confluent Schema Registry with from_avro standard function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57950215/how-to-use-confluent-schema-registry-with-from-avro-standard-function)

In addition, we started pointing to the following jars for kafka-client

kafka-clients-2.4.1.jar

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Apparently the issue happens when yarn is used and disappear when the master is set to local

Comment: Check this one
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48882723/integrating-spark-structured-streaming-with-the-confluent-schema-registry

Snippet :

    # The magic goes here:
    # Skip the first 5 bytes (reserved by schema registry encoding protocol)
    .selectExpr("substring(value, 6) as avro_value") \
    .select(from_avro(col("avro_value"), schema).alias("data")) \
    .select(col("data.my_field")) \

Comment: I might have found a solution, which is related to an issue between the driver (serialize) and executor (deserialize) jar conflict. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=953144

Answer (score 0):

The error disappears when you set the master to `local[*]`. Anyhow, the problem seems to be related with a jar conflict between the driver and the executor: they use different versions of the kafka-clients library.

To solve the problem you may want to launch jobs with

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark \
 --class <YOUR_CLASS> \
 --jars target/scala-2.12/<COMPILED_JAR_FILE>.jar,kafka-clients-2.4.1.jar  \
 --cluster <CLUSTER_NAME> \
 --region= <YOUR_REGION> \
 --properties spark.jars.packages=org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.0.1,spark.executor.extraClassPath=org.apache.kafka_kafka-clients-2.4.1.jar,spark.driver.extraClassPath=org.apache.kafka_kafka-clients-2.4.1.jar
```

This works in my case. Please check https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12/3.0.1 for further details on versions.