# How pass Basic Authentication to Confluent Schema Registry?

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, spark-structured-streaming, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I want to read data from a confluent cloud topic and then write in another topic.

At localhost, I haven't had any major problems. But the schema registry of confluent cloud requires to pass some authentication data that I don't know how to enter them:

> basic.auth.credentials.source=USER_INFO
>
> schema.registry.basic.auth.user.info=:
>
> schema.registry.url=https://xxxxxxxxxx.confluent.cloudBlockquote

Below is the current code:

```
import com.databricks.spark.avro.SchemaConverters
import io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.{CachedSchemaRegistryClient, SchemaRegistryClient}
import io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer
import org.apache.avro.Schema
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object AvroConsumer {
  private val topic = "transactions"
  private val kafkaUrl = "http://localhost:9092"
  private val schemaRegistryUrl = "http://localhost:8081"

  private val schemaRegistryClient = new CachedSchemaRegistryClient(schemaRegistryUrl, 128)
  private val kafkaAvroDeserializer = new AvroDeserializer(schemaRegistryClient)

  private val avroSchema = schemaRegistryClient.getLatestSchemaMetadata(topic + "-value").getSchema
  private var sparkSchema = SchemaConverters.toSqlType(new Schema.Parser().parse(avroSchema))

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder
      .appName("ConfluentConsumer")
      .master("local[*]")
      .getOrCreate()

    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

    spark.udf.register("deserialize", (bytes: Array[Byte]) =>
      DeserializerWrapper.deserializer.deserialize(bytes)
    )

    val kafkaDataFrame = spark
      .readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaUrl)
      .option("subscribe", topic)
      .load()

    val valueDataFrame = kafkaDataFrame.selectExpr("""deserialize(value) AS message""")

    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

    val formattedDataFrame = valueDataFrame.select(
      from_json(col("message"), sparkSchema.dataType).alias("parsed_value"))
      .select("parsed_value.*")

    formattedDataFrame
      .writeStream
      .format("console")
      .option("truncate", false)
      .start()
      .awaitTermination()
  }

  object DeserializerWrapper {
    val deserializer = kafkaAvroDeserializer
  }

  class AvroDeserializer extends AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer {
    def this(client: SchemaRegistryClient) {
      this()
      this.schemaRegistry = client
    }

    override def deserialize(bytes: Array[Byte]): String = {
      val genericRecord = super.deserialize(bytes).asInstanceOf[GenericRecord]
      genericRecord.toString
    }
  }

}
```

I think I have to pass this authentication data to CachedSchemaRegistryClient but I'm not sure if so and how.

Comment: This is the actual error: `[error] (run-main-0) io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Unauthorized; error code: 401
[error] io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Unauthorized; error code: 401`

Comment: Where in the code do you do bytes-avro conversion and access schema registry?

Comment: The conversion is being performed by the udf deserialize.
the access to the registration scheme now I am trying it in the following way:


`val schemaRegistryURL = "url"

  val restService = new RestService(schemaRegistryURL)

  val props = Map(
    "basic.auth.credentials.source" -> "USER_INFO",
    "schema.registry.basic.auth.user.info" -> "SECRET",
    "schema.registry.url" -> schemaRegistryURL
  )

  val javaProps = scalaProps.asJava

  var schemaRegistryClient = new CachedSchemaRegistryClient(restService, 100, javaProps)`

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the code to keep everything in one place? I'd like to see the UDF to deserialize avro (that as far as I understand uses the registry).

Answer (score 17):

I've finally been able to pass the properties.

I leave the lines that gave the solution.

```
val restService = new RestService(schemaRegistryURL)

  val props = Map(
    "basic.auth.credentials.source" -> "USER_INFO",
    "schema.registry.basic.auth.user.info" -> "secret:secret"
  ).asJava

  var schemaRegistryClient = new CachedSchemaRegistryClient(restService, 100, props)
```