# Spark Structured Streaming with Schema Registry integration for Avro based messages

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, avro, spark-structured-streaming, confluent-schema-registry

We have a use-case where we are trying to consumer multiple Kafka topics (**AVRO messages**) integrating with Schema registry.
We are using Spark Structured streaming (**Spark version : 2.4.4**) , Confluent Kafka (Library version: 5.4.1) for the same:

```
val kafkaDF: DataFrame = spark.readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "<bootstrap.server>:9092")
  .option("subscribe", [List of Topics]) // multi topic subscribe
  .load()
```

We are selecting value from the above DF and using Schema to de-serialize the AVRO message

```
val tableDF = kafkaDF.select(from_avro(col("value"), jsonSchema).as("table")).select("*")
```

The Roadblock here is , since we are using multiple Kafka topics , we have have integrated all our JSON schema into MAP with **key** being the **topic name** and **values** being the **respective schema**.
**How can we do a lookup using the same map in the select above? we tried UDF but it returns a "col" type but jsonSchema has to be of String type. Also it Schema is different for different topics**

Couple of added questions:

1. Is the above approach correct for consuming multiple topics at once?
2. Should we use single consumer per topic?
3. If we have more number of topics how can we achieve parallel topic processing, cos sequential might take substantial amount of time.

Comment: Are you transforming the data? Storing to where?

Comment: there is tad bit of transformation required.

Comment: OK, otherwise KAFKA Connect would have been a better option

Comment: you can map the topics indeed, but it depends on volume. Are you writing to different output areas?

Comment: yes we are, mapping topics is fine, but what about schema , that's one per topic right? how can we combine them.

Comment: what do you mean by combine?

Comment: like in this statement : val tableDF = kafkaDF.select(from_avro(col("value"), jsonSchema).as("table")).select("*")  , we expect one JSON schema per Topic, how can use the same for multi topic ?

Comment: each own schema or 1 general overall schema?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Integrating Spark Structured Streaming with the Confluent Schema Registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48882723/integrating-spark-structured-streaming-with-the-confluent-schema-registry)

Answer (score 1):

Without checking it all, you appear to be OK on the basics with from_avro, etc. from_json, etc.

1. https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-streaming-consume-and-produce-kafka-messages-in-avro-format/ can guide you on first part. This also very good https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark-structured-streaming/two-topics-two-schemas-one-subscription-apache-spark-structured-streaming/read#filter_topic.
2. I would do table.*
3. Multiple, multiple schemas --> read multiple such versions *from .avsc* or code yourself.
4. For consuming multiple topics in a Spark Streaming App the question is how many per App? No hard rule except obvious ones like large consumption vs. smaller consumption and if order is important. Executor resources can be relinquished.
5. Then you need to process all the Topics separately like this imho - `Filter on Topic` - you can fill in the details as I am a little rushed - using the `foreachBatch` paradigm.
6. Not sure how you are writing the data out at rest, but the question is not about that.

Similar to this, then to process multiple Topics:

```
...
... // Need to get Topic first
stream.toDS()
      .select($"topic", $"value")
      .writeStream
      .foreachBatch((dataset, _) => {
         dataset.persist() // need this

         dataset.filter($"topic" === topicA)
                .select(from_avro(col("value"), jsonSchemaTA)
                .as("tA"))
                .select("tA.*")
                .write.format(...).save(...)

         dataset.filter($"topic" === topicB)
                .select(from_avro(col("value"), jsonSchemaTB)
                .as("tB"))
                .select("tB.*")
                .write.format(...).save(...)
          ...
          ...
         dataset.unpersist()
         ...
         })

         .start().awaitTermination()
```

but blend with this excellent answer: [Integrating Spark Structured Streaming with the Confluent Schema Registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48882723/integrating-spark-structured-streaming-with-the-confluent-schema-registry)

Comment: Thanks for this :)
Can we have "jsonSchemaTA" and "jsonSchemaTB" as a lookup from Schema registry , that is where we are currently stuck, even using UDF it doesn't work

Comment: As I wrote elsewhere, though, `from_avro` doesn't work with the Schema Registry