# spark shell (spark 3.0.0) adding packages confluent kafka 5.5.1 issues with javax.ws.rs-api

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

My local win10 WSL back unbuntu,
In ubuntu, i have installed spark3.0.0, confluent platform 5.5.1 (manually downloaded)

when I try to run either spark-shell or spark-submit (below is shell example)

```
spark-shell\
 --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.0.0,\
org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:3.0.0,\
io.confluent:kafka-schema-registry:5.5.1,\
io.confluent:kafka-avro-serializer:5.5.1
```

**they both have issues like below:**

```
:::: WARNINGS
        [NOT FOUND  ] javax.ws.rs#javax.ws.rs-api;2.1.1!javax.ws.rs-api.${packaging.type} (15ms)

    ==== local-m2-cache: tried

      file:/home/min/.m2/repository/javax/ws/rs/javax.ws.rs-api/2.1.1/javax.ws.rs-api-2.1.1.${packaging.type}

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::

        :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        :: javax.ws.rs#javax.ws.rs-api;2.1.1!javax.ws.rs-api.${packaging.type}

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::



:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: [download failed: javax.ws.rs#javax.ws.rs-api;2.1.1!javax.ws.rs-api.${packaging.type}]
```

tried to add below, did **not help**.

```
 --repositories https://packages.confluent.io/maven/\
```

**note:** if i remove the last two confluent platform packages, it has no problems.

**please help**, maybe i have to downgrade either of the version.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy maybe?

Comment: no. no proxy. the end goal is to try to read avro message off confluent kafka, trying to follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48882723/integrating-spark-structured-streaming-with-the-confluent-schema-registry

Comment: I will give up this one for now. as It was a rabbit hole for my end goal.

Answer (score 1):

This is issue in sbt https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/3618

A workaround for now is to replace `javax.ws.rs-api` with `jakarta.ws.rs-api`.

Luckily for you confluent already done this in their libraries so if you use version `5.5.2` like this :

```
io.confluent:kafka-schema-registry:5.5.2,
io.confluent:kafka-avro-serializer:5.5.2
```

It should be fixed.