# org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable error in UDF

Tags: scala, apache-spark, serialization, spark-avro

We are trying to fetch data from kafaka and doing deserialization for avro data format. Code is working fine till kafkaDataframe where data is fetched from kafka topic but when trying to extract value from kafkaDataframe using deserialize() UDF method. It is throwing exception as Task not serialiable and java.io.NotSerializableException: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient. Request anyone to help us to resolve this issue.

Code is copied from [medium link] https://github.com/xebia-france/spark-structured-streaming-blog/blob/master/src/main/scala/AvroConsumer.scala

```
import com.databricks.spark.avro.SchemaConverters
import io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.{CachedSchemaRegistryClient, SchemaRegistryClient}
import io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer
import org.apache.avro.Schema
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer

val topic = "topic"
val kafkaUrl = "kafkaUrl"
val schemaRegistryUrl = "schemaRegistryUrl"
val schemaRegistryClient = new CachedSchemaRegistryClient(schemaRegistryUrl, 128)


class AvroDeserializer extends AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer with Serializable {
    def this(client: SchemaRegistryClient) {
      this()
      this.schemaRegistry = client
    }

    override def deserialize(bytes: Array[Byte]): String = {
      val genericRecord = this.deserialize(bytes).asInstanceOf[GenericRecord]
      genericRecord.toString
    }
  }

val kafkaAvroDeserializer = new AvroDeserializer(schemaRegistryClient)

val avroSchema = schemaRegistryClient.getLatestSchemaMetadata(topic + "-value").getSchema

val sparkSchema = SchemaConverters.toSqlType(new Schema.Parser().parse(avroSchema))

object DeserializerWrapper extends Serializable{
    val deserializer = kafkaAvroDeserializer
}

spark.udf.register("deserialize", (bytes: Array[Byte]) => DeserializerWrapper.deserializer.deserialize(bytes))

val kafkaDataFrame = spark.read.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaUrl).option("subscribe", topic).option("startingOffsets", "earliest").load()

kafkaDataFrame.show() // This code work fine in console

val valueDataFrame = kafkaDataFrame.selectExpr("deserialize(value) AS message")

valueDataFrame.show() // This code is not working and throwing exception as "org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable" and "java.io.NotSerializableException: AvroDeserializer"
```

Below is the full exception trace for your reference.

```
scala> valueDataFrame.show()
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:345)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:335)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:159)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2299)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1.apply(RDD.scala:850)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1.apply(RDD.scala:849)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.mapPartitionsWithIndex(RDD.scala:849)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:613)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.getByteArrayRdd(SparkPlan.scala:247)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:337)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3278)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2489)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2489)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$52.apply(Dataset.scala:3259)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3258)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2489)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2703)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:254)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:723)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:682)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:691)
  ... 49 elided
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient, value: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient@40199d5e)
    - field (class: $iw, name: schemaRegistryClient, type: class io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@2d579733)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@539c833d)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@7b217a33)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@6b21a869)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@5f849a79)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@73372652)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@4ecd395f)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@15dbd88e)
    - field (class: $line25.$read, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $line25.$read, $line25.$read@234a21e9)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $line25$read, type: class $line25.$read)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@31d635ba)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@1172a648)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@69f7da24)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@53e0c50)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@5c5761f)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@67306a84)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@615a30bd)
    - field (class: $line38.$read, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $line38.$read, $line38.$read@6cc45cf2)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $line38$read, type: class $line38.$read)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@1b4bfdb)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@29a1aca8)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@70ebf6d8)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@9febb7c)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@2f2f6aaa)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@5b7bccc3)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@68fa9450)
    - field (class: $line41.$read, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $line41.$read, $line41.$read@170f2883)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $line41$read, type: class $line41.$read)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@3fa0f38a)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $outer, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@48754a85)
    - field (class: $anonfun$1, name: $outer, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $anonfun$1, <function1>)
    - element of array (index: 3)
    - array (class [Ljava.lang.Object;, size 4)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$10, name: references$1, type: class [Ljava.lang.Object;)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$10, <function2>)
  at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
  at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:46)
  at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:100)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:342)
  ... 80 more
```

Answer (score 1):

The error means you cannot use an instance of `CachedSchemaRegistryClient` shared on all Spark executors because it cannot be serialized.

As you cannot make it serializable (both because you don't own it and it doesn't make sense as it's probably a class that holds some IO/network resources), you have to somehow create one instance on each executor.

How to achieve that in your case? I'm not sure to be honest because you're using the client in a UDF and I don't know its lifecycle. You should look for the way to make a UDF use a non-serializable class.