# Parquet files to avro and kafka SourceRecord

Tags: java, apache-kafka, parquet, avro, apache-kafka-connect

I'm trying to convert parquet files into SourceRecords. I'm currently stuck on generating connect schema from avro schema. I'm able to read parquets to GenericRecords:

```
public static Seq<GenericRecord> genericRecordsOf(Seq<String> parquets) {
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.setBoolean(AVRO_COMPATIBILITY, true);
    config.setBoolean("parquet.avro.add-list-element-records", false);
    config.setBoolean("parquet.avro.write-old-list-structure", false);
    config.setClass("parquet.avro.data.supplier", SchemaTest.class, AvroDataSupplier.class);
    config.set("fs.s3a.impl", S3AFileSystem.class.getCanonicalName());
    return parquets.flatMap(input -> {
          Builder<Record> builder = Try(() -> AvroParquetReader
              .<Record>builder(HadoopInputFile.fromPath(new Path(input), config))
              )
              .get();
          return readRecords(builder);
        }
    );
  }

  private static List<GenericRecord> readRecords(Builder<Record> builder) {
    return Try
        .withResources(builder::build)
        .of(SchemaTest::readRecords)
        .get();
  }

  private static List<GenericRecord> readRecords(ParquetReader<Record> reader) {
    List<GenericRecord> records = new LinkedList<>();
    Record genericRecord = readRecord(reader);
    while (genericRecord != null) {
      records.add(genericRecord);
      genericRecord = readRecord(reader);
    }
    return records;
  }

  private static Record readRecord(ParquetReader<Record> reader) {
    return Try.of(reader::read).get();
  }
```

The issue is while I'm trying to make connect data from it, using `io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroData.toConnectData(avroSchema, avroValue)`.
The exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Mismatched names: name already added to SchemaBuilder (org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Decimal) differs from name in source schema (cedingrate)
        at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroData.toConnectSchema(AvroData.java:1969)
        at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroData.toConnectSchema(AvroData.java:1669)
        at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroData.toConnectSchemaWithCycles(AvroData.java:2000)
        at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroData.toConnectSchema(AvroData.java:1836)
        at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroData.toConnectSchema(AvroData.java:1669)
        at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroData.toConnectSchema(AvroData.java:1803)
        at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroData.toConnectSchema(AvroData.java:1645)
        at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroData.toConnectData(AvroData.java:1326)
        at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroData.toConnectData(AvroData.java:1307)
        at com.tryg.data.ingestors.guidewire.factories.SchemaTest.lambda$main$0(SchemaTest.java:103)
        at io.vavr.Value.forEach(Value.java:340)
        at com.tryg.data.ingestors.guidewire.factories.SchemaTest.main(SchemaTest.java:102)
```

and avro schema generated by `AvroParquetReader` is (fragment):

```
"type": "record",
  "name": "spark_schema",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "cedingrate",
      "type": [
        "null",
        {
          "type": "fixed",
          ***"name": "cedingrate",
          "size": 16,
          "logicalType": "decimal",
          "precision": 38,
          "scale": 6
        }
      ],
      "default": null
    },
...
```

I have debugged into the `AvroData` code and found out that the issue is that `AvroData` expects `"name": "org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Decimal"` instead of `"name": "cedingrate"` in the place marked with `***`.
Cedingrate is the field name in parquet file. The parquet files are being generated by Guidewire cloud data access framework.
I dont know where to look for further.
Any tips apreciated.
Regards, Dawid.

Comment: I suggest you simply use SparkSQL to read parquet and write to Kafka. Otherwise, Confluent already has an S3 source connector

Comment: Thanks for quick answer.
Ad1. I have read the data already. The schema is my problem. Can sparkSQL provide shema for confluent?
Ad2. I would have to write my own format by extending `StorageObjectFormat`. In this class I would have to implement `extractRecord` method and provide kafka connect value and schema. Getting schema from parquet file is what I'm struggling right now in question.

Comment: SparkSQL can read Parquet, yes, in one line of code, too. After you get a dataframe, its schema can easily be extracted, and Spark has Avro functions to convert dataframe schemas to Avro schemas... It [can integrate with schema registry since data is just bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48882723/integrating-spark-structured-streaming-with-the-confluent-schema-registry), although, Flink has better support for Registry builtin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR; use `io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroData` class from kafka-connect-avro-data:6.2.6 dependency to convert avro to connect data.

The above solution will work with `io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroData` class which is delivered in kafka-connect-avro-data (maven dependency) with version up to 6.2.6.
In version 7.0.0, avro fixed schemas, which are being converted to connect schemas by `io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroData`, are treated as schemas with type `FIXED`. Up to 7.0.0, they are treated as BYTE type schemas.

There is some kind of incompatibility between parquet-avro dependency (the way how AvroParquetReader builds fixed schemas from parquet files) and kafka-connect-avro-data (the way how  AvroData converts schemas from avro to connect). I wasn't able to find out which of those components work according to avro schema requirements.