# Spark stream read from Kafka with Abris and, schema registry by latest won't sync

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming, confluent-schema-registry

I have a Spark stream that reads from Kafka Avro messages and generates a dataframe according to a schema by the latest version. I' m using abris to do so and it looks like that.

```
import za.co.absa.abris.avro.functions.from_avro
import za.co.absa.abris.config{AbrisConfig, FromAvroConfig}

val abrisConfig = AbrisConfig.fromConfluentAvro
.downloadReaderSchemaByLatestVersion
.andRecordNameStrategy(schemaName, recordNamespace)
.usingSchemaRegistry(schemaRegistryUrl)
```

Then I can read my Avro message to Kafka based on this abrisConfig.

As you can see I want to get the latest version of the schema, but when the stream is running on the spark cluster and read from Kafka base on this abris config it "stuck" with the latest schema version he downloaded when he first start to run.

So if my schema has been updated my stream that read from Kafka with the abris config does not "refresh/sync" with the new latest schema version, so if the new schema has a new column I can lose it.

Any suggestions on how I can tell Abris to auto-refresh every batch?

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended to "refresh" since the Dataframe schema would be created once, at the application initialization. This means even if the Avro schema changes in the topic, then new fields would be dropped or mapped back to the schema of the consumer application until it is restarted.

The alternative would be to define your own deserializer with parsing to `GenericRecord`, then treating that as JSON, effectively, as shown in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57999615/2308683), but even with that approach, you'd still need to modify your code to selectively pull certain fields that have been added by any producer.