# PySpark - Trying to push data to kafka topic using KafkaAvroSerializer via JVM Gateway

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to push data to kafka topic via PySpark. I am using the [KafkaAvroSerializer](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/fundamentals/serdes-develop/serdes-avro.html) because I have heard it also registers to schema registry when data is pushed & also takes care of schema evolution.

Here is what I have come up with so far.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import BinaryType


def avro_serializer(*row):

    jvm = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()._jvm  # Get JVM object

    # Initialize KafkaAvroSerializer
    kafka_avro_serializer = jvm.io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer()
    kafka_avro_serializer.configure(config_map, False)

    # Serialize row to Avro
    row_dict = {str(i): row[i] for i in range(len(row))}
    avro_bytes = kafka_avro_serializer.serialize(kafka_topic, row_dict)

    return avro_bytes


avro_udf = udf(avro_serializer, BinaryType())

all_columns = df.columns
df_avro = df.withColumn("value", avro_udf(*all_columns))

df_avro.selectExpr(f"CAST({all_columns[0]} AS STRING) AS key", "value") \
    .write \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka_bootstrap_servers) \
    .option("kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_SSL") \
    .option("kafka.sasl.mechanism", "PLAIN") \
    .option("kafka.sasl.jaas.config",
            f'org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="{topic_api_key}" password="{topic_api_secret}";') \
    .option("topic", kafka_topic) \
    .option("schema.registry.url", schema_registry_url) \
    .save()
```

All goes fine, until the last command when I get.

```
23/09/17 09:35:49 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 28.0 (TID 38)
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 3, in avro_serializer
  File "/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 485, in getOrCreate
    return session
  File "/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 514, in getOrCreate
    return SparkContext._active_spark_context
  File "/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 189, in __init__
    SparkContext._assert_on_driver()
  File "/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 2390, in _assert_on_driver
    raise RuntimeError("SparkContext should only be created and accessed on the driver.")
RuntimeError: SparkContext should only be created and accessed on the driver.
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:561)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$2.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$2.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:514)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:760)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaWriteTask.execute(KafkaWriteTask.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaWriter$.$anonfun$write$2(KafkaWriter.scala:72)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1529)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaWriter$.$anonfun$write$1(KafkaWriter.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaWriter$.$anonfun$write$1$adapted(KafkaWriter.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$foreachPartition$2(RDD.scala:1009)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$foreachPartition$2$adapted(RDD.scala:1009)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$runJob$5(SparkContext.scala:2303)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:139)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:554)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1529)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:557)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
23/09/17 09:35:49 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 28.0 (TID 38) (172.17.0.98 executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 3, in avro_serializer
  File "/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 485, in getOrCreate
    return session
  File "/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 514, in getOrCreate
    return SparkContext._active_spark_context
  File "/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 189, in __init__
    SparkContext._assert_on_driver()
  File "/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 2390, in _assert_on_driver
    raise RuntimeError("SparkContext should only be created and accessed on the driver.")
RuntimeError: SparkContext should only be created and accessed on the driver.
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:561)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$2.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$2.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:514)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:760)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaWriteTask.execute(KafkaWriteTask.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaWriter$.$anonfun$write$2(KafkaWriter.scala:72)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1529)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaWriter$.$anonfun$write$1(KafkaWriter.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaWriter$.$anonfun$write$1$adapted(KafkaWriter.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$foreachPartition$2(RDD.scala:1009)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$foreachPartition$2$adapted(RDD.scala:1009)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$runJob$5(SparkContext.scala:2303)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:139)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:554)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1529)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:557)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
23/09/17 09:35:49 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 28.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py", line 364, in runcode
    coro = func()
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 1396, in save
    self._jwrite.save()
  File "/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
  File "/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/errors/exceptions/captured.py", line 175, in deco
    raise converted from None
pyspark.errors.exceptions.captured.PythonException: 
  An exception was thrown from the Python worker. Please see the stack trace below.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 3, in avro_serializer
  File "/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 485, in getOrCreate
    return session
  File "/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 514, in getOrCreate
    return SparkContext._active_spark_context
  File "/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 189, in __init__
    SparkContext._assert_on_driver()
  File "/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 2390, in _assert_on_driver
    raise RuntimeError("SparkContext should only be created and accessed on the driver.")
RuntimeError: SparkContext should only be created and accessed on the driver.
```

I have a very vague understanding of why this occurs, but I absolutely have no idea how to fix this. Can anyone help? What modifications would I need to do to the code to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

The UDF is ran on the executors. You'll be unable to create the SparkSession there, which is what's happening, since it's running under a different environment than where you originally created `df`

If you looked at code linked in the previous question, it uses this to get access to the JVM classes, not SparkSession

```
jvm_gateway = SparkContext._active_spark_context._gateway.jvm
```

Otherwise, you need to create/config `kafka_avro_serializer` outside of the UDF, since it doesn't need redefined over every executor

Regarding the UDF itself; Avro doesn't need numbered fields. You already have column names, so use those. Otherwise, there's not really a good generic way to serialize any schema to Avro, since types matter; for example, you could have a nested Struct with arrays and other fields from Spark, but you're currently only iterating over top level columns of the dataframe (including the key)

Also, your first column isn't guaranteed to be the key, so I suggest renaming a specific column before writing rather than indexing a list

Comment: Thanks. But even with that, it just results another error. Tried to solve that too and one error lead to another. So I skipped this and tried with the separate kafka topic data push + schema registry register. That worked for data producing, but when it came to consumption via gcs sink connector, it failed due to lack of magic byte.

I will try with other solutions 1 last day today and if I'm unable to proceed, I will give up with this approach.

Pyspark does not have first hand support from confluent kakfa and the jvm gateway thing is very confusing. Not finding working example code.

Comment: Unclear why you even need Spark when confluent-kafka-python works fine, without Java installation, and will work as expected with Kafka GCS Sink connector

Comment: We will be handling big data so we need distributed computing. @OneCricketeer

Comment: Sounds like you haven't tried it. Kafka defaults to 1MB per record, max. There's nothing big about that. Librdkafka processes data faster than the JVM client, anyway. So using a JVM won't help there, and using a different producer client won't make anything worse than running into errors..

Comment: 1 MB per message means 1 MB per dataframe row, which is huge. When I said big data, I meant tables with millions of rows, which confluent can easily handle. A record row going over 1 MB is very rare, usually only happens when clients dump all json response data into a column, at which point we will just blacklist the column.

We are more concerned about the system being able to handle large numbers of record data at a time than the processing speed. In our system speed is not as critical as scalability, thus the pyspark approach.

Comment: Spark dataframe would not have "millions of rows". Dataframes are broken into batches, and parallelized to executors. `confluent-kafka-python` can handle that as well, using a native generator/cursor connected to a database. There is no reason to keep millions of rows in memory at any given time. Also, it is just "Kafka" broker handling the requests, not "Confluent"

Comment: While database cursor will prevent complete data loading at once, that method will still limit the activity to one server, which means a single point of failure. Using spark avoids this issue, while also making the system scalable (Think we running 100 such jobs simultaneously, we can just add/remove node at any time.) Previously I had trouble integrating `confluent-kafka-python` with pyspark, but after reading your comment I gave it one more shot. After working all day, I was able to produce it with schema key and value and successfully tested it end to end. Thanks for your assistance. ☺

Comment: It's true there might be scalability issues. I just haven't had good luck with Spark and Schema Registry myself at scale. I created a JIRA in the Spark project to try to get them to modify `to_avro` function to support a Registry call, but they closed it rather quickly. Flink, on the other hand, does have a Confluent Serde library