# pyspark parses all fields in a json serialized message from kafka as NULL

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I'm running Kafka and Spark (pyspark) and being able to write and read JSON-serialized messages with the python library confluent-kafka. The messages have the following schema:

```
schema_str = """{
    "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
    "title": "Exposure",
    "description": "Exposure description",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "description": "unique identifier",
        "type": "number"
      },
      "name": {
        "description": "exposure name",
        "type": "string"
      },
      "past_due": {
        "description": "days of past due",
        "type": "number"
      },
      "forborne": {
        "description": "forbearance",
        "type": "number"
      }
    }
  }"""
```

and I defined the Json schema for pyspark as follows:

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField("id", IntegerType()),
    StructField("name", StringType()),
    StructField("past_due", IntegerType()),
    StructField("forborne", IntegerType())
])
```

To read the stream with pyspark I wrote the following code

```
streaming_df = spark.readStream\
    .format("kafka") \
    .options(**kafka_options) \
    .option("startingOffsets", "latest") \
    .load()

value_df = streaming_df.select(from_json(col("value").cast("string"),schema).alias("value"))

exploded_df = value_df.selectExpr('value.id', 'value.name', 'value.past_due', 'value.forborne')

query = exploded_df \
        .writeStream \
        .format("console") \
        .outputMode("append") \
        .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

Unfortunately, the output from the stream is

```
Batch: 1
-------------------------------------------
+----+----+--------+--------+
|  id|name|past_due|forborne|
+----+----+--------+--------+
|NULL|NULL|    NULL|    NULL|
|NULL|NULL|    NULL|    NULL|
|NULL|NULL|    NULL|    NULL|
|NULL|NULL|    NULL|    NULL|
|NULL|NULL|    NULL|    NULL|
|NULL|NULL|    NULL|    NULL|
|NULL|NULL|    NULL|    NULL|
+----+----+--------+--------+
```

Note: the deserialization with the library confluent-kafka works fine.

Anyone can help with this? I suppose I am not defining well the schema for spark

Comment: Why don't you test your schema format in isolation without the streaming pipeline. Just provide a json document with few input rows and parse it with the struct schema and see if it works.

Comment: Ignoring Avro bits, you need to use `substring("value", 6)` first to actually get the real JSON record content that `from_json` can use - https://stackoverflow.com/a/65818275/2308683 More details https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/fundamentals/serdes-develop/index.html#wire-format

Comment: I m using JSON but yes the problem was some extra characters at the beginning, I solved it with a regex_extract