How to deserailize confluent kafka avro messages in spark scala without using abris or removing magic bytes
I am trying to deserialize messages written in confluent avro format.
I know we can use abris or remove magic bytes but Is there a way we can do it without any of these two methods?
Below is what I am trying but with no luck
`
        import java.nio.file.{Files, Paths}
        import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig
        import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
        import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
        import org.apache.spark.sql.avro.functions._
        import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.Trigger
        import io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer

        import org.apache.avro.Schema
        import org.apache.avro.Schema.Parser
        import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet
        import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients
        import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils

        object ReadFromKafka {
          System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "C:\\hadoop")
          def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
            val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
            sparkConf.setAppName("ConfluentConsumer").setMaster("local[*]")
            val spark = SparkSession.builder()
              .appName("AvroKafkaStructuredStreaming")
              .config(sparkConf)
              .getOrCreate()

            import spark.implicits._
            val kafkaBootstrapServers = "bootstrapserver"
            val kafkaTopic = "topic"
            val schemaRegistryUrl = "schemaregistryurl:8081"


            // Function to fetch Avro schema from Schema Registry
            def fetchAvroSchema(topic: String, schemaRegistryUrl: String, version: String): Schema = {
              val client = HttpClients.createDefault()
              val url = s"$schemaRegistryUrl/subjects/$topic-value/versions/$version/schema"
              println("url--"+url)
              val request = new HttpGet(url)
              val response = client.execute(request)
              val jsonSchema = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity)
              client.close()
              new Parser().parse(jsonSchema)
            }

            val df = spark.read
              .format("kafka")
              .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaBootstrapServers)
              .option("subscribe", kafkaTopic)
              .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
              .option("failOnDataLoss", "false")
              .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", 10)
              .option("value.deserializer", classOf[KafkaAvroDeserializer].getName)
              .option("schema.registry.url", schemaRegistryUrl)
              .option("mode", "PERMISSIVE")
              .load()

            import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig



            // Fetch Avro schema dynamically
            val avroSchema = fetchAvroSchema(kafkaTopic, schemaRegistryUrl, "latest").toString()
            println("avroSchema "+avroSchema)
            
            val deserializedDF = df.select(from_avro($"value", avroSchema).as("data"))
            // val deserializedDF =  df.select(from_avro(expr("substring(value, 6)"), avroSchema)) // this works

            deserializedDF.show(false)

            /* val query = deserializedDF.writeStream
               .outputMode("append")
               .format("console")
             //  .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("10 seconds"))
               .start()*/

            //query.awaitTermination()
          }


        }

`
below is the error that I am getting:
Caused by: org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Malformed data. Length is negative: -5057
at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.readString(BinaryDecoder.java:308)

spark version used: 3.12
scala : 2.12.14
below is my build.sbt file:
scalaVersion := "2.12.14"
val sparkVersion = "3.1.2"

resolvers += "confluent" at "https://packages.confluent.io/maven/"
  resolvers += "confluent" at "https://packages.confluent.io/maven/"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql-kafka-0-10" % "3.1.2"
libraryDependencies += "io.confluent" % "kafka-avro-serializer" % "7.5.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-avro" % "3.1.2"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion %"compile",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion % "compile"

)

dependencyOverrides ++= {
  Seq(
    "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" %% "jackson-module-scala" % "2.12.3",
    "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-annotations" % "2.12.3",
    "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % "2.12.3",
    "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.12.3"
  )
}``



SparkSQL from_avro function expects plain Avro data, not the Confluent Wire Format. That is why "expr(substring(value, 6)") will work with it. Other options were posted here, but are mostly all the same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48882723/integrating-spark-structured-streaming-with-the-confluent-schema-registry

in confluent docs, here is an example  in java  [link] (https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/fundamentals/serdes-develop/serdes-avro.html)
here they are not removing or doing any operation on magic bytes but able to deserialize. Do we not have anything from spark out of the box that can handle confluent avro formatted messages? and what is the use of this parameter
.option("value.deserializer", classOf[KafkaAvroDeserializer].getName)

The deserializer internally extracts the magic byte and schema id, but Spark doesn't use value.deseriaiilizer property, so you should remove that (and the registry url). Data is always consumed as bytes. So therefore, you can't copy plain Kafka client examples as shown from the docs. Confluent published a separate blog for Spark https://www.confluent.io/blog/consume-avro-data-from-kafka-topics-and-secured-schema-registry-with-databricks-confluent-cloud-on-azure/#step-7

for this select(from_avro(expr("substring(value, 6)"), schemaJson)) you mentioned in another link that it is inelegant, you said this coz of any performance reasons or is there any other reason ?

I don't recall saying that. But it ignores any schema id within each message, causing you to lookup the latest schema separately (assuming it's backwards compatible).
